# Substituir todos os parâmetros '&' de uma consulta no SQLDeveloper

Tags: sqldeveloper

Tenho uma consulta que utilizar varias vezes o mesmo parâmetro, no SQLDeveloper, chama Variável de Substituição (VS), por exemplo, `&empresa`.

Se utilizo essa VS com a consulta abaixo:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    pedido
WHERE empresa   = &empresa;
```

O SQLDeveloper antes de executar a consulta, pergunta qual o valor da VA, então informo e ele realiza a consulta.

> **Problema:**
>   Se crio uma consulta mais complexa, utilizando a mesma VA mais de uma vez, o SQLDeveloper pede o valor da VA toda a vez. Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma pedir somente uma vez.

<sub>*P.S.: Não quero usar outra variável para guardar o valor da VA e então utilizar a variável em vários lugaras.*</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando a syntax `&variavel`, o valor atribuído a mesma é temporário, ou seja, só irá ser utilizada na cláusula SQL atual.

Se utilizar a syntax `&&variavel`, o valor atribuído é permanente, ou seja, pode ser utilizada a mesma variável em diversas cláusulas SQL.

A [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25259_01/appdev.31/e24285/intro.htm#RPTUG10720) pode te ajudar.

Comment: Interessante, estou migrando do PLSQL para o SQLDeveloper, e testei aqui no PLSQL não funciona o `&&`, somente o `&`, que tem a mesma funcionalidade. Obrigado

Comment: Fiz exatamente o mesmo teste aqui, e percebi o mesmo.